# Handle Huge (Local) Matrix in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

So I'm trying out collaborative filtering in Spark. Let's say I have 1 million users, and I'm using SparkML's `pyspark.ml.stat.Correlation.corr` to compute Pearson correlation between user pairs. By documentation, this method [returns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.stat.Correlation):

> A DataFrame that contains the correlation matrix of the column of vectors. This DataFrame contains a single row and a single column of name ‘$METHODNAME($COLUMN)’.

The matrix (`DenseMatrix`) itself is not distributed ([local](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html)), which, from my understanding, must fit into the memory of my driver machine.

Question:

1. Does the data frame containing this matrix span over multiple machines? I know Spark partitions data frame, but I think that's the case with multiple rows?
2. How can I make this HUGE local matrix distributed RDD / data frame (so I can **do things**)? I can do nothing with it if it is local.

```
thisMatrix = thisDataFrame.take(1)[0][0]
sc.parallelize(thisMatrix.toArray())
```

will not work (because it fetches the matrix into a single machine).

Comment: Computing item-wise similarity will make the matrix smaller (tho still very big in my point of view), but I would love to know how to solve my question **in general**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misunderstood the docs a little bit. `Corelation.corr` returns a `DataFrame`, which is exactly as parallelized as any other Pyspark `DataFrame`. If you were to perform the following call:

```
pearsonCorr = Correlation.corr(dataset, 'features', 'pearson')
```

no data will be sent back to the driver node. That will be true up to the point that an actual action, such as `collect`, is called on `pearsonCorr`. The `DenseMatrix` mentioned in the [`Correlation` docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.stat.Correlation) is in fact the result of a `collect` call, not the call to `Correlation.corr` itself:

```
pearsonCorr = Correlation.corr(dataset, 'features', 'pearson').collect()[0][0]
print(str(pearsonCorr).replace('nan', 'NaN'))

DenseMatrix([[ 1.        ,  0.0556...,         NaN,  0.4004...],
             [ 0.0556...,  1.        ,         NaN,  0.9135...],
             [        NaN,         NaN,  1.        ,         NaN],
             [ 0.4004...,  0.9135...,         NaN,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: I understand. But how can I do anything with the matrix in parallel? I think I have to `collect` the dataframe, extract the matrix, then make it some distributed structure. When I collect the dataframe there will be memory issues.

Comment: Follow up to your answer: how does spark distribute dataframes with only **one** row? Or, how does it handle a huge cell? I thought spark stores different rows distributed, but a row / cell always lives on one machine? Can you refer me to docs on this?